# meteor js each block remove line feed

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

In meteor.js, if you use an `each` block, it ends with a line feed that breaks my layout.

How can I remove it?

e.g. `<textarea>{{#each}}{{text}}{{/each}}</textarea>` will have an extra at the end of it, screwing up the textarea's layout.

Comment: How about pre-processing your text in a helper function and call that helper within the textarea instead?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a helper function that would do the trick:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  concatLines: function (text) {
    var concatenated = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
      concatenated += text[i];
    }
    return concatenated;
  }
});
```

And in your template:

```
<textarea>{{concatLines text}}</textarea>
```